# Look for tables which contain at least one column name that matches a regular expression

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive we can use the command below to look for tables which name matches a given regular expression pattern:

```
hive> show tables like 'regex_pattern';
```

I'm trying to search all the tables that contains at least one column which name matches a given regular expression pattern. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: for the record `*customer*` is not a valid regular expression

Comment: I am telling you what you are using is **not** a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), it is some kind of glob syntax, but it is **not** [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax, so it is **not** a regular expression. Try putting that in any regex site like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and make it work, I can save you some time, it won't. So whatever it is, it is **not** a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the columns in a HIVE table using DESCRIBE command as below:

```
hive> DESCRIBE <table name>
```

Alternative:

```
hive> SHOW COLUMN STAT <table name>
```

This command will list you all of the columns. You can next use Unix shell to pipe in the count command and filter accordingly

```
$ hive -e 'DESCRIBE <table name>' | grep "your match string"
```

Loop it for all the list of tables and store it in some output file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to search a few tables since we need to run `hive -e ...` for each table (which may takes some time for lots of tables).

Comment: Actually I've found a table which holds metadata from other hive tables, so we just need to run a query there.